# Logging Handlers: How do I make sure I am not making two?

Tags: python, logging

**Edit:  I ended up answering the beef of my question so that I can have a working logging module. However, I still have a related question.  See my answer below.**

I am trying to implement logging by always logging to the temporary directory of whatever os I am in.  To do this I have written the following function.

```
import logging, tempfile, os, sys

def getlog(logname, filename = 'python.log', directory = None):
   '''returns a logger with logname that will print to filename and directoryname.'''
   if directory == None:
      fd, fname = tempfile.mkstemp()
      directory = os.path.dirname(fname)

   fullpath = directory + '/' + filename

   mylog = logging.getLogger(logname)
   hdlr = logging.FileHandler(fullpath)

   formatter = logging.Formatter('L:%(name)s M:%(module)s T:%(asctime)s > %(levelname)s: %(message)s')
   hdlr.setFormatter(formatter)
   mylog.addHandler(hdlr)
   mylog.setLevel(logging.INFO)
   mylog.info('NEW LOGGER STARTED')
   return mylog

if __name__ == '__main__':
   log = getlog('testing')
   log.info('working?')
   log.info('yes, seems to be working')

   log2 = getlog('testing')
   log2.info('still working?')
```

Here is the output:

```
L:testing M:easy_log T:2011-04-11 15:30:14,315 > INFO: NEW LOGGER STARTED
L:testing M:easy_log T:2011-04-11 15:30:14,316 > INFO: working?
L:testing M:easy_log T:2011-04-11 15:30:14,316 > INFO: yes, seems to be working
L:testing M:easy_log T:2011-04-11 15:30:14,316 > INFO: NEW LOGGER STARTED
L:testing M:easy_log T:2011-04-11 15:30:14,316 > INFO: NEW LOGGER STARTED
L:testing M:easy_log T:2011-04-11 15:30:14,316 > INFO: still working?
L:testing M:easy_log T:2011-04-11 15:30:14,316 > INFO: still working?
```

As you can see, it is now outputting double.  However, the logging module is rather confusing, and I do not know of a way to find out if a log has already been instantiated, or if a log object already has a handler.  Some help would be appreciated.

Edit: to add a little more detail, I am planning on calling this in several modules, essentially trying to replace the "logging.getLogger" call.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I ended up answering my own question.  Here is the code

```
global IS_SETUP 
IS_SETUP = False
def setuplogger(filename = 'python.log', directory = None, format = 'L:%(name)s M:%(module)s T:%(asctime)s > %(levelname)s: %(message)s'):
   global IS_SETUP
   if directory == None:
      fd, fname = tempfile.mkstemp()
      directory = os.path.dirname(fname)

   logging.basicConfig(filename = directory + '/' + filename, format = format)
   IS_SETUP = True

def getlog(logname, level = logging.INFO):
   '''returns a logger with logname that will print to filename and directoryname.'''
   if IS_SETUP == False:
      setuplogger()

   mylog = logging.getLogger(logname)

   mylog.setLevel(level)
   mylog.info('NEW LOGGER STARTED')
   return mylog
```

This avoids the double config.  Also, apparently Basic config would work even if it were called multiple times.

If anyone knows how to check what handlers are on a log object, I would still like to know.  It seems absolutely impossible.

Comment: FWIW you can just access "mylog.handlers" to iterate through the list of installed handlers